# mysql master to master replication with one slave

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb

I have 3 servers

- **Server A** master to **Server B**
- **Server B** master to **Server A** and **Server C**
- **Server C** slave to **Server B**

When I add table to **Server A**, it replicated on **server B** but not in **Server C**

When I add table to **Server B**, it replicated to **server A** and **Server C**

Why is this happening, is there any configuration to make sure when I add table in Server A, it replicate on both Server B and Server C

Thank you

Comment: I will readily admit that MySQL replication isn't my field of expertise, but this setup sounds rather convoluted to me. Might that contribute to your problems?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling it might sound convoluted, but it's a reasonably common and supported configuration.  A and B are redundant writable masters, and C is a read-only replica for read offloading, reporting, analytics, or backups.  Replication cascades are a relatively straightforward setup, and the answer below probably has nailed it; `log_slave_updates` has to be enabled for slaves of B to see events replicated from A.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Sounds fair enough. Like I said, this isn't my field of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable `log-slave-updates` in configuration of server B. This option allow server B to save updates received from server A to its binlog, so server C can see it as new transaction and will replicate it. If this option is disallowed, server B just apply changes received from server A but not propagate it into server C. More info you can find in [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates).